# How to execute an IF url or route contains ... function with LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5 for one of my projets and after hours spend I'm asking for little help!!

I need to execute a Script (Google Gtag) if the user is on this exact url :

```
https://website.com/offer/payment/success/[dynamic]
```

or/and comes from:

```
https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/[dynamic]
```

I tried this without succes:

```
@if(!Request::is('offer/payment/success/*'))
....
@endif
```

Does someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_contains()` for this purpose.The `str_contains()` function checks whether the string (parameter #1) contains the second string.

```
@if(str_contains(url()->current(), 'offer/payment/success/'))
     ........
@endif
```

As per official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#accessing-the-current-url) details of `url()->current().`

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work with me!

Can we try with previous/referer domain ( https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/[dynamic]) or Route ( Route::get('/payment/success/{id}', 'OfferController@successStripe')->name('pay.stripe.session.success'); ?

Comment: I solve it with: 
@if(Route::current()->getName() != 'pay.stripe.session.success' )

Comment: you are using named routes ?

Comment: It doesn't work like a charm! Before the thank you page "https://website.com/offer/payment/success/[dynamic]" and the checkout page "https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/[dynamic]" we have the cart page "https://website.com/offer/[dynamic] and the IF fonction works also on this page... 

How to avoid this? Can I use another method with URL or Referer/previous page ?

Comment: you can use @if(Route::current()->getName() == 'pay.stripe.session.success' ) and in else you can perform action for other pages.

Comment: Now the IF function doesn't work at the cart page, as expected, but also in the thank you page. I'm lost

Comment: I solve it by deleted "*" : 

    @if(str_contains(url()->current(), 'offer/payment/success/'))

Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that.